# preg_match expression for extracting everything but "[]"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
<some string>[]<somestring>
```

example

```
variable[]_abc
```

How can I get everything except `[]` from the string using `preg_` in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\[\]/','',$string);
```

Comment: This is overkill for the task described. Also a write up for what you are doing would be good.

Comment: It wery simple task, I don't know wot I can descript.

Comment: The `/` are delimiters all regexs in PHP require delimiters. The back slashes are escaping the brackets because brackets in regex are special characters, unless escaped.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove `[]` use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$newstring = str_replace('[]', '' $string);
```

There is no need for a regex to remove static characters.